# Is it possible to put a shortuct to my app as a Suggested App on the lock screen of iOS 8 without a hardware iBeacon, based on location alone?

Tags: ios, ios8, ibeacon, lockscreen, geofencing

My company has an internally-developed iOS app.

I've seen the iBeacon-based app icons on the lock screen when I go places like 7-11 or Walmart, and they take me to apps already on my phone.

This thing basically:
[image]

I understand iBeacon can also suggest apps I don't have yet but I haven't experienced that yet personally.

I think it would be useful for my internally-developed app to show the app's icon when the user is in the building, since it's likely that they would need to use the app while in the building, and there's not another app competing for a suggestion (i.e, when you're in the building you're not near a 7-11, Walmart, etc.)

However what I'm seeing mixed messages on is whether or not there's a way to do this ***without*** a hardware-based iBeacon. Based on geofencing alone, basically.

To be clear I'm talking about displaying this only **when the person is in the building** and **has the app already installed**. I'm not trying to broadcast it to anyone who doesn't have the app.

Do I still need a hardware-based iBeacon to do this? If not, is there any documentation on how to do this with an already-installed app based on geofencing alone? I've tried to look this up but I'm not having any luck so either I'm using the wrong terminology or I've just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a geofence using `CoreLocation`.  All you need to do is create a `CLCircularRegion` instance that maps your office location, and start monitoring for that region in your `AppDelegate`.  If you get a `didEnterRegion` callback, you will see the icon you describe on iOS8.

The trick is, of course, that it can often be hard to trip geofences indoors.  If you can live with making your region big enough to trigger as you near your office, then this could be a solution.